# ArrayList Length

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble getting the arraylist length to show in my for loop. I'm a beginner/novice with programming so I might be completely off base here. The output for the `ArrayList` is showing up as 0. What I'm trying to do it compare a string from a `jTextBox` with an arraylist and see if the `String` exists within the `List`.

```
public static void ValidateProtocolCompatiblity(FAS_Define[] faslist, String selectedProtocol, String selectedFAS){
     for (int index=0; index < faslist.length;index++){
        if (faslist[index].getName() == selectedFAS)
            for (int j=0; j < faslist[index].getSupportedProtocol().toArray().length;j++){       
                fasProtocolList.add(faslist[index].getSupportedProtocol().toString());

            }
    }
```

Here is my original array list based on the constructor

```
        FAS_Define[] fasList = new FAS_Define[10];
        fasList[0] = new FAS_Define("FAS2552", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("iSCSI", "FCoE"))); 

        ValidateProtocolCompatiblity(fasList,protocolField, fasField);
```

Class for the getter/setter/constructor outlining the original array list

```
public class FAS_Define {
private int id;
private String name;
private List<String> supportedProtocol; 

private static int numberofDevice = 0;

public FAS_Define(String cName, ArrayList<String> cSupportedProtocol){
    this.name = cName;
    this.supportedProtocol = new ArrayList<String>();

    numberofDevice++;
    id = numberofDevice;
}
public String getName(){return name;}
public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}

public List<String> getSupportedProtocol(){return supportedProtocol;}
public void setSupportedProtocol(List<String> supportedProtocol){this.supportedProtocol = supportedProtocol;}
```

Comment: `if (faslist[index].getName() == selectedFAS)` don't compare strings with `==`. Use `equals` method. More info at "[How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)"

Comment: OP has plenty of bugs that could benefit from reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
faslist[index].getSupportedProtocol().toArray().length
```

Use:

```
faslist[index].getSupportedProtocol().size()
```

There's no need to convert the arrayList to array. And for getting the element of the array list at a given index, use:

```
faslist.get(index).getSupportedProtocol().toString()
```

Instead of

```
faslist[index].getSupportedProtocol().toString()
```